# Виснут все приложения созданные в Unity (Ryzen 5 3400G, Windows 10)

Tags: unity3d, directx-11

Друзья столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Работая в Unity 2021 я сделал Build под Windows, хотел с другом поделиться.
Запускаю build и комп в синий экран (Windows 10 LTSB 2016).

В ошибке написано про DirectX Kernel.

Пробую обновить Директ, пишет все ок - свежая. Запускаю DXDIAG - тоже все норм.
Комп купил в этом году 2021, все дрова с диска под 10 64 бита. 10ка корпоративная LTSB 2016.

Скачиваю новые дрова с АМД. При установки пишет 184 ошибка (Гуглил, про нее толком ничего нет)

Может кто сталкивался? Можно победить, без переустановки Винды?.
Много программ уже стоит, не хочу все заново ставить.

В поддержке АМД сказали Windows обновите до 20Н+. Я им написал купите мне его и я обновлю.
По идее корпоративная винда не обновляется полностью до последней :(
А мог бы Про выбрать :(

Comment: Цитирую "Много программ уже стоит, не хочу все заново ставить.", вы можете убрать все нужные программы на отдельный том (не тот на котором Windows, обычно это диск D)  в папку и все важные программы тоже перекинуть туда

Comment: Саму ошибку, которую вам показывает на синем экране, отправьте.

Comment: Спасибо, но они потом работать не будут. Стоит Unity, MS VS, PhotoShop, Maya и т.п. с кучами настроек под себя, кистями, палитрами, клавиши переназначены везде. Все это пропадет.

Comment: VIDEO DXGKRNL FATAL ERROR

Comment: Попробовал удалить дрова на Вегу11. Build запустился но тормозит. Проблема в дровах. Но новые не поставить :(

Comment: Если вам нужна поддержка старой версии ОС, значит ставьте старую версию Unity которая будет нормально работать со старой версией драйверов, наверное?

Comment: Как вариант хорош. Ставить 2016? по году Винды?